# Finding the inverse of possibly non-invertible interpolation function

Tags: interpolation, inverse

Consider the following sample code

```
pts = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -10, 10}];
foo = Interpolation[pts];
Plot[InverseFunction[foo][y], {y, 0, 10}]
```

From the plot, we see that `InverseFunction[foo][y]` only finds the positive `x` corresponding to the interpolation function `foo`, but ideally, I would like the inverse function to be something like `ifoo[y]={x1,x2,...}`, where `x1,x2,...` are the possible solutions for $y=x^2$.

In the end, I would like to generalize this to a multi-dimensional function. More specifically, let's say I have a set of data `{{{x1,y1},{f1,g1}},...}` and apply interpolation so that we get the function `foo[x,y]={f[x,y],g[x,y]}`. Now I would like to invert this function so that `ifoo[z,w]={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` where `{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...` are the possible solutions towards `foo[x,y]={z,w}`.

How would one be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Define the inverse with [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pts = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -10, 10}];
foo = Interpolation[pts];

inv[y_?NumericQ, branch_ : Automatic] :=
 Module[{x, init = If[branch === Automatic, -10, 10]},
  x /. FindRoot[foo[x] == y, {x, init}]]
```

Augmenting [`InverseFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)

```
Plot[{InverseFunction[foo][y], inv[y]},
 {y, 0, 100}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.85, .25}]]
```

[image]

Replacing `InverseFunction`

```
Plot[{inv[y, "+"], inv[y]}, {y, 0, 100}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.85, .25}]]
```

[image]

Comment: So in your code, it seems that you need to know that there are two solutions, one positive one negative, but for a general function that may not be true, such as a bifurcation diagram or something else.

Comment: You would need to plot `foo` to determine how many branches there are and the initial starting value to use for each branch.

Comment: @Andrew an inverse *function* is supposed to be one-to-one, so if you know multiple solutions are possible, you need to do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the two inverses by generating a differential equation of foo and solve with NDSolve applied to two initial conditions. Even derivatives of inverse function can be produced.

```
pts = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, -10, 10}];
foo = Interpolation[pts];

dinv = D[foo[x[y]] == y, y]

xsol[y_] = 
   x[y] /. NDSolve[{dinv, #}, x, {y, 100, 0}] & /@ {x[100] == -10, 
x[100] == 10} // Quiet

{Plot[xsol[y], {y, 0, 100}, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1], 
 Plot[xsol'[y], {y, 0, 100}, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1]
}
```

[image]