# How can I find the inverse of an interpolating function?

Tags: differential-equations, functions, interpolation, inverse

I am numerically solving the coupled differential equations (for $t[\tau]$ and $r[\tau]$) below. Mathematica outputs two interpolating functions as solutions. I would like to invert one of these solutions - $t[\tau]$. That is, how can I obtain $\tau[t]$ from the interpolating function $t[\tau]$?

```
M = 500;
r0 = 3 M;
uppertime = 1996.733812103724;

s = NDSolve[{t'[τ] == Sqrt[1 - 2 M/r0]/(1 - 2 M/r[τ]),
r''[τ] - (M/r[τ]^2)/(1 - 2 M/r[τ])*
  r'[τ]^2 + (M/
    r[τ]^2)*(1 - 2 M/r0)/(1 - 2 M/r[τ]) == 0, t[0] == 0,
r[0] == r0, r'[0] == 0}, {t, r}, {τ, 0, uppertime}]

Plot[Evaluate[{t[τ], r[τ]} /. s], {τ, 0, uppertime},
PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

<sub>(Cross-posted [on the Wolfram forum](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2573265).)</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219554/finding-the-inverse-of-possibly-non-invertible-interpolation-function

Answer (score 13):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

M = 500;
r0 = 3 M;
uppertime = 1996.733812103724;

sys = {t'[τ] == Sqrt[1 - 2 M/r0]/(1 - 2 M/r[τ]), 
   r''[τ] - (M/r[τ]^2)/(1 - 2 M/r[τ])*
      r'[τ]^2 + (M/r[τ]^2)*(1 - 2 M/r0)/(1 - 2 M/r[τ]) == 0, 
   t[0] == 0, r[0] == r0, r'[0] == 0};

s = NDSolve[sys, {t, r}, {τ, 0, uppertime}] // Quiet;

plt = Plot[Evaluate[{t[τ], r[τ]} /. s], {τ, 0, uppertime},
  PlotRange -> {0, 10000},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    {HoldForm[t[τ]], HoldForm[r[τ]]},
    {.4, .6}]]
```

[image]

Extract the points for the first curve

```
pts = Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]];
```

The inverse function is the interpolation of the reversed points.

```
inv = Interpolation[Reverse /@ pts];
```

Comparing the inverse function with the inverse using [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t[τ], τ} /. s], {τ, 0, uppertime},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10000}, Automatic}, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio ],
 Plot[inv[τ], {τ, 0, 10000},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[
    ColorData[97][2], Dashed]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The `// Quiet` makes it look like you're hiding something...

Comment: @MichaelE2 - the `uppertime` value of `1996.733812103724` goes slightly beyond what `NDSolve` can handle. If you prefer, truncating to `1996.733812` will avoid the warning.

Answer (score 6):

`InverseFunction` also work in interpolating function. `InverseFunction[t] /. s[[1]]` is what you want.

```
Clear[inverse1];
{a, b} = {t[0] /. s[[1]], t[1996] /. s[[1]]};
inverse1 = InverseFunction[t] /. s[[1]];
Plot[inverse1@x, {x, a, b}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

To faster the drawing, we can use `FunctionInterpolation`.

```
Clear[inverse2];
inverse2 = 
  FunctionInterpolation[InverseFunction[t]@x /. s[[1]], {x, a, b}];
Plot[inverse2@x, {x, a, b}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: Try `inverse1[b - 10]`. Why chop off `b`/`uppertime`?

Answer (score 5):

An other way with no loss of precision is to take the coordinates and values generated by NDSolve, reverse coordinates and values and generate the inverse interpolating function tau[t].

```
M = 500;
r0 = 3 M;
uppertime = 1996.733812103724;

s = NDSolve[{t'[\[Tau]] == Sqrt[1 - 2 M/r0]/(1 - 2 M/r[\[Tau]]), 
   r''[\[Tau]] - (M/r[\[Tau]]^2)/(1 - 2 M/r[\[Tau]])*
      r'[\[Tau]]^2 + (M/
        r[\[Tau]]^2)*(1 - 2 M/r0)/(1 - 2 M/r[\[Tau]]) == 0, t[0] == 0,
    r[0] == r0, r'[0] == 0}, {t, r}, {\[Tau], 0, uppertime}]


tsol[tau_] = t[tau] /. s[[1]];

taucoordinates = First@tsol["Coordinates"];

tvalues = tsol["ValuesOnGrid"];

tp = Transpose[{tvalues, taucoordinates}];

ListPlot[tp, PlotRange -> All]

tau = Interpolation@tp

Plot[tau[t], {t, 0, tvalues[[-1]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
             GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We demonstrate how to get a fast accurate inverse.  `InverseFunction` is highly accurate when it works, but it tends to be slow. It depends on `FindRoot` which is not guaranteed to succeed.  In fact, it does not succeed near the singularity of the OP's solution, but that is no great loss, imho.  Simple interpolation methods that switch $(x,y)$ to $(y,x)$ are fast and easy, but they may or may not be accurate enough. The ones currently present, Bob Hanlon's and Akku14's, are accurate to about 7 digits on average. Often that will be perfectly fine. I'll give one that's better for cases in which greater accuracy is needed.

Inverting the interpolation table is an easy way to compute the inverse function of an interpolation. It will give exact entries at the interpolation nodes. Between the nodes there may be significant interpolation error, since the inverse function of a polynomial is not always well represented by another polynomial of low degree.  It is certainly the case in the OP's example in which the interpolating order is 3. To get a more accurate result, a higher degree interpolant may be used based on the derivatives of the given interpolation; however, this approach meets with limited success. Adding the first and second derivatives yields an improvement of only a order of magnitude or a little more in relative accuracy.  We'll look at this method, simply because I had a function for computing the inverse this way, and maybe it would be of interest.

A better way is to construct an interpolant of the inverse function between each step, by picking points between the nodes instead of adding derivative information at the nodes.  Adding just the midpoints improves the interpolation by an order of magnitude, similar to adding derivative values at the nodes. One might be tempted, say, [to use the Chebyshev points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114065/4999).  Indeed, this theoretically should be able to construct an arbitrarily accurate inverse.  However, one has to solve `y == tIFN[tau]` for many, many values of `y`. This should not be hard to program, but it felt like a lot of work compared to, say, letting `NDSolve` do almost all the work for you, which we demonstrate below.

#### NDSolve method

An important strategy is to advance `NDSolve` successively from one step in the OP's solution to the next with `` NDSolve`Iterate[] ``. This will insure that the result is accurate. A solution produced by `NDSolve` such as the OP's solution has weak singularities (e.g. the third derivative is discontinuous at each step/node). By stopping and starting the integration at each step, we insure that `NDSolve` does not try to step across a singularity.  For instance error estimation is based on the ODE and solution being continuously differentiable through a certain order.
Another strategy is to use the `"Projection"` method to improve each step.
Note that the use of `InterpolationOrder -> All` reduces the interpolation error in `NDSolve` solutions.
Note also that the code gives warnings because of the ridiculously small `"IterationSafetyFactor"`. This small factor is what makes the answer have machine-precision accuracy. We're basically setting an impossibly small error tolerance for the solution. There is no need to increase `MaxIterations`; in fact, I reduced it from the default `32` to `16`, because it is good enough in this case.

```
tIFN = t /. First@s;  (* OP's solution s *)
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   {tau'[t] == 1/tIFN'[tau[t]], tau[tIFN[0]] == 0}, 
   tau, {t, tIFN[0], tIFN[uppertime]}, InterpolationOrder -> All,
   Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {tIFN@tau[t] == t}, 
     "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1/10^10, MaxIterations -> 16
     },
   PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxStepFraction -> 1];
NDSolve`Iterate[state, #] & /@ tIFN@"ValuesOnGrid";
sINV = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]
ndINV = tau /. First[sINV];
{tmin, tmax} = First@ndINV@"Domain";
```

#### Inverting the interpolation data including derivatives

If you take all the checks out, the code is fairly simple. (Some like to see careful code; others think it obscures the main idea.) There are a few lines to calculate derivative formulas for inverse functions, which demonstrates one of the cool things about Mathematica: letting it generate symbolically generate the code you need to use in another function. In this case, they are used to create the table for `yy`.  And then the `Interpolation@Transpose@...` line that creates the answer.  The checks for invertibility may be of interest. Like most numerical procedures, they are approximate and not foolproof.  For instance, `Interpolation[{{{0.},0.,4.},{{1.},1.,4.}}]` will pass the checks, but it is not an invertible function.  However, `NDSolve` is unlikely to produce such a pathological case.

```
(* formulas for the derivatives of the inverse function
 * in terms of the values of the derivatives of the function *)
invD // ClearAll;
mem : invD[n_Integer?Positive] := mem = Evaluate[
     Block[{f, y},
      Derivative[n][InverseFunction[f]][y] /.
        {Derivative[k_][_][_] :> Slot[k]} //
       Simplify]
     ] &;

(* inverts an interpolating function if it is (probably)
 * monotonic; otherwise returns InverseFunction[f]  *)
invIF // ClearAll;
invIF::univ = "invIF defined for univariate interpolation functions only.";
invIF::ninv = 
  "Interpolating function is not monotonic. InverseFunction is returned.";
invIF[f_InterpolatingFunction] := With[{x = f@"ValuesOnGrid",
    y = f@"Coordinates",
    yy = Table[
      Derivative[k][f]["ValuesOnGrid"], 
      {k, First@f@"InterpolationOrder" - 1}]},
   (* monotonicity data *)
   With[{monotone1 = DeleteDuplicates@Sign@Differences@x,
     monotone2 = DeleteDuplicates@Sign[f'@"ValuesOnGrid"]},
    (* interpolation of f^(-1) with derivative values *)
    Interpolation@Transpose@{List /@ x,
        First@y,
        Sequence @@ Table[invD[k] @@ yy, 
          {k, First@f@"InterpolationOrder" - 1}]} /;
     (* univariate check *)
     Length@y == 1 &&
      (* monotonicity checks *)
      monotone1 === monotone2 && MatchQ[monotone1, {1} | {-1}]
    ]];
invIF[f_InterpolatingFunction] := 
  (Message[invIF::ninv];
    InverseFunction[f]) /; Length@f@"Domain" == 1;
invIF[f_InterpolatingFunction] := 
  (Message[invIF::univ]; Null /; False);

myTau = invIF[tIFN];
```

#### Error plots

The main take-away is that the `NDSolve` method achieves machine-precision accuracy, or thereabouts.
We use `ndINV` and `myTau` (from `invIF[]`) from above and the solutions from Bob Hanlon `invBH` (= `inv`) and Akku14 `invAk` (= `tau`).  One should not be too concerned about the increase in error near the singularity of `t[τ]`. We include the interpolation nodes in the plot to show that the errors in `invAk` and the `invIF` solution are zero at those points. The spikes go down way below the plot range, but that cannot be shown without making the comparison of the methods impossible.  (I tend to use Akku14's method most often.)  We separate the plots to make the comparison easier.

```
Plot[{
  (invBH@tIFN@tau - tau)/($MachineEpsilon + tau) // RealExponent,
  (invAk@tIFN@tau - tau)/($MachineEpsilon + tau) // RealExponent,
  (myTau@tIFN@tau - tau)/($MachineEpsilon + tau) // RealExponent,
  (ndINV@tIFN@tau - tau)/($MachineEpsilon + tau) // RealExponent},
 {tau, 0, uppertime}, PlotRange -> {-20.1, 0.1},
 PlotPoints -> {200, First@tIFN@"Coordinates"}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Thread@Directive[ColorData[97] /@ {3, 2, 5, 1}, Opacity[0.5]],
 PlotLegends -> {"BobHanlon", "Akku14", "invIF", "NDSolve"},
 GridLines -> {None, {-8, -6}}]
```

[image]

#### Addendum

*Side note on the OP's `uppertime`:*
The number looks like it might have been copied from a `NDSolve::ndsz` message.  When you change the limits `a` or `b` of `{τ, a, b}` in `NDSolve`, you can affect the steps ever so slightly.  When I run the OP's code, I get an error/warning:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At τ == 1996.7338120977709, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Τhe value for `τ` is very close to `uppertime`. If I add a little to `uppertime`, I will get different stopping time that differs only in the last few digits. Somehow `NDSolve` is adjusting the step sizes, but I cannot explain exactly what is going on.