# substituting oscillatory solution with an averaged version efficiently

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am numerically solving the below ODE which has a highly oscillatory solution. This is fine.

```
Mpl = 10^19; \[CapitalLambda]qcd = 2/10;
m = 1; 
ti = 2 10^12;
tf = 4 10^14;
eqns={a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] + m^2 ((2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2 t)/Mpl )^4 a[t] == 0, a[ti] == 1, a'[ti] == 0};
st = NDSolve[eqns, a[t], {t, ti, tf}, WorkingPrecision -> 10];
En[t_] := (t^(7/2) a[t]^2)/(3.48 10^46) /. st
LogLinearPlot[En[t], {t, ti, tf}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However I would like to substitute what I'm plotting (the function En[t] in code) with an 'averaged' version.
I've gone about this the explcit way - see below - by defining a new function which at every point averages over many cycles but plotting this takes forever. There must be a more efficient way? If not in defining the new function, at least in plotting it...

```
s\[Tau] = st /. t -> \[Tau];
EnAvg[t_] := NIntegrate[(a[\[Tau]] /. s\[Tau])^2/(0.2 t), {\[Tau], 0.9 t , 1.1 t}][[1]]
(* Takes forever *)
LogLinearPlot[EnAvg[t], {t, ti, tf}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Side question: Why `WorkingPrecision -> 10`? It's slower and less precise that using machine precision. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can use the NDSolve method [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270962/how-can-i-find-the-inverse-of-an-interpolating-function/271063#271063) to integrate `a[t]^2` (instead of the inverse function), using ``NDSolve`Iterate[state, #] & /@ Flatten[a[t] /. st /. t -> "Grid"]`` for the `Iterate` stage. Or you can simultaneously integrate `a[t]^2` in the original NDSolve call.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way, among many...

Grab the points generated for your plot (I find this trick repeatedly useful in working with Mathematica)

```
plot = LogLinearPlot[En[t], {t, ti, tf}, PlotRange -> All];
points = Cases[plot, Line[data_] :> data, Infinity][[1]];

points[[1;;3]]
(* {{28.3242, 0.000325107}, 
   {28.3258, 0.000326961}, 
   {28.3274, 0.000328826}}
*)
```

Since the `Plot` function is adaptive, the X-axis values aren't sampled on a fixed grid, so use `MovingMap` to smooth the data. You get to pick the window and the smoothing function. Two obvious choices are `Mean` and `Median`. The third input is the window size. The `None` will ensure the same number of points in the smoothed data as the original, but the smoothing window "overhangs" the data at the end.

```
smooth1 = MovingMap[Mean, points, .3, None];
smooth2 = MovingMap[Mean, points, 3, None];
smooth3 = MovingMap[Median, points, .3, None];
smooth4 = MovingMap[Median, points, 3, None];

ListLinePlot[{smooth1, smooth2, smooth3, smooth4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can solve  this diffequation anylytically with DSolve.

```
Mpl = 10^19; \[CapitalLambda]qcd = 2/10;
m = 1;
ti = 2 10^12;
tf = 4 10^14;
eqns = {a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] + 
      m^2 ((2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2 t)/Mpl)^4 a[t] == 0, a[ti] == 1, 
    a'[ti] == 0} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

eqns2 = Subtract @@@ eqns // Together // Numerator;

asol = a /. First@DSolve[Thread[eqns2 == 0], a, t]

En[t_] = (t^(7/2) asol[t]^2)/(348 10^44) // FullSimplify

(*   ((2 + Sqrt[3]) (t^3)^(
   5/6) (\[Pi] (t^3)^(1/6)
       BesselJ[-(13/12), 8/46875] BesselJ[1/12, t^3/
       46875000000000000000000000000000000000000] + \[Pi] Sqrt[t]
       BesselJ[-(1/12), t^3/
       46875000000000000000000000000000000000000] BesselJ[13/12, 8/
       46875])^2)/(597381591796875000000000000000000000000000000000 \
Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])   *)

Plot[En[t], {t, ti, tf }, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Plot is different from your plot, since your plot suffers of workingprecision for higher t. Now regard En2[t] to see the two only osccilarory BesselJ terms, which oscillate to zero for high t.

```
rules = {BesselJ[1/12, t^3/
     46875000000000000000000000000000000000000] -> bes1, 
   BesselJ[-(1/12), t^3/46875000000000000000000000000000000000000] -> 
    bes2};

En2[t_] = En[t] /. rules

(*   ((2 + Sqrt[3]) (t^3)^(
 5/6) (bes1 \[Pi] (t^3)^(1/6) BesselJ[-(13/12), 8/46875] + 
   bes2 \[Pi] Sqrt[t]
     BesselJ[13/12, 8/
     46875])^2)/(597381591796875000000000000000000000000000000000 \
Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])   *)

LogLinearPlot[
 BesselJ[1/12, t^3/46875000000000000000000000000000000000000], {t, ti,
   tf}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

I leave it to you to extract behavior for higher t, averaging oscillaroty terms.

Comment: Thank you. I know in this particular simple case one can solve analytically but I am actually interested in more complicated versions where there can only be a numerical handle.

Answer (score 1):

My second answer. Numerical solution.

Use NDSolve to integrate En in the same run as calculating a.

```
Mpl = 10^19; \[CapitalLambda]qcd = 2/10;
m = 1;
ti = 2 10^12;
tf = 4 10^14;
eqns = {a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] + 
      m^2 ((2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2 t)/Mpl)^4 a[t] == 0, a[ti] == 1, 
    a'[ti] == 0} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

eqns2 = Subtract @@@ eqns // Together // Numerator;

nsol = First@
  NDSolve[Join[
    Thread[eqns2 == 0], {Enint'[t] == (t^(7/2) a[t]^2)/(348 10^44), 
     Enint[ti] == 0}], {a, Enint}, {t, ti, tf}, MaxSteps -> 5 10^5, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 80, AccuracyGoal -> 10]

Plot[a[t] /. nsol, {t, ti, tf}, WorkingPrecision -> 70, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]

Plot[Enint[t] /. nsol, {t, ti, tf}, WorkingPrecision -> 70, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

You see, oscillations do not compensate to constant value, but continuous integral of En is growing. But please check, whether accuracy is high enough.

Get En[t] by simply differetiating the integral Enint[t].

```
Plot[Enint'[t] /. nsol, {t, ti, tf}, WorkingPrecision -> 70, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

You see, En[t] has a mean value of about 2.5, which is the gradient/slope in the picture of Enint[t].

```
(Enint[4 10^14] - Enint[2 10^14])/(2 10^14) /. nsol
```

(*   2.653850693851505840381830   *)

More exact: Linear fit