# The result of interpolating a table is not numeric

Tags: differential-equations, functions, numerical-integration, interpolation, numerical-value

I'm having trouble in using interpolating functions with Mathematica. Some interpolating functions I defined, say $f[x]$, if evaluated in a specific point $x_0$ correctly return the numeric value $N[f[x_0]]$, while some others return a non-numeric value $\{f[x_0]\}$, as if the interpolating function were a list of array-like values. This leads me to problems in the subsequent manipulation of these interpolating functions since, for example, when integrating such functions one can get error messages like "*Integrand is not numerical at {x} = {...}*". I'm now going to show the problem in detail.

I'm using Mathematica to numerically solve a differential equation $d\chi/d\phi=F(\phi)$, with a given function $F(\phi)$, to find $\chi(\phi)$. Then I want to reverse the newly found relationship to obtain $\phi(\chi)$. The problem I'm facing is independent of the complexity of the function $F(\phi)$, so from now on I will just assume $F(\phi)\equiv1$.
Then we are just numerically solving $\,\chi(\phi)=\int d\phi\,$ to find that $\chi(\phi)=\phi$ and reverse this to obtain $\phi(\chi)=\chi\,$.
The code I wrote is the following:

```
xMax = 40 ;
STEPS = 10000 ;
dx = xMax/STEPS;

CHI[x_] = y[x] /. First[NDSolve[{D[y[x], x] == 1, y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, xMax}] ] ;
chi = Interpolation[Table[{{x}, CHI[x]}, {x, 0, xMax, dx}]] ;
phi = Interpolation[Table[{CHI[x], {x}}, {x, 0, xMax, dx}]] ;
```

Here "**CHI[x_]**" should be the solution of the differential equation $\,d\chi/d\phi=1\,$. I then defined "**chi**" to be an interpolating function of "**CHI[x_]**", namely $\chi(\phi)$. Then I defined the interpolating function "**phi**" by simply inverting the order of the values I give in the `Table` command, namely to find $\phi(\chi)$.

Now I would expect "**chi**" and "**phi**" to be two interpolating functions, so that by asking for `chi[15]` and `phi[15]` in the code I get the numeric values of the two functions in the point "15" (which obviously must both be equal to 15).
By doing this, I get

```
CHI[15]
chi[15]
phi[15]

Out[7] = 15.
Out[8] = 15.
Out[9] = {15.}
```

Here is my problem: why both "**CHI**" and "**chi**" returns a numeric value 15, while "**phi**" returns a non-numeric array-like value {15}?

This is critical for my code, because I then have to work with $\phi(\chi)$ to figure out a potential and numerically integrate that potential... and it gives me the error output "*Integrand is not numerical at {x} = {...}*" for some "*{...}*" value of x.
In fact, if in this trivial case just shown I ask for `NIntegrate` the interpolating function "**phi**", i get the error

```
NIntegrate[phi[x], {x, 0, chi[xMax]}]

NIntegrate::inum: Integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,40.}},{5,3,0,{10001},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,<<3>>},{{0.,0.004,0.008,0.012,0.016,0.02,0.024,0.028,0.032,0.036,<<9991>>}},{{{0.}},{{0.004}},{{0.008}},{{0.012}},{{0.016}},{{0.02}},{{0.024}},{{0.028}},{{0.032}},{{0.036}},<<9991>>},{Automatic}][x] is not numerical at {x} = {0.318293}.
NIntegrate::inum: Integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,40.}},{5,3,0,{10001},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,<<3>>},{{0.,0.004,0.008,0.012,0.016,0.02,0.024,0.028,0.032,0.036,<<9991>>}},{{{0.}},{{0.004}},{{0.008}},{{0.012}},{{0.016}},{{0.02}},{{0.024}},{{0.028}},{{0.032}},{{0.036}},<<9991>>},{Automatic}][x] is not numerical at {x} = {0.318293}.
Out[10] = NIntegrate[phi[x], {x, 0, chi[xMax]}]
```

While the N-integration of "**chi**" (which has numeric values) correctly returns

```
NIntegrate[chi[x], {x, 0, xMax}]

Out[11] = 800.
```

being $\int_0^{40}x\,dx=800\,$.

What is the problem? Why am I not having numeric values in $\phi(\chi)$?

Comment: Hi, try replacing `{CHI[x], {x}}` by `{CHI[x], x}`. I have no idea why you used`{x}` here.

Comment: Hi @user293787, what you suggest actually works! I have just a little doubt about it: why the use of ```{x}``` seems to work in ```{{x}, CHI[x]}``` while it does not work in ```{CHI[x], {x}}```? Do you advise me to always use ```x``` instead of ```{x}``` in cases like these? In the meantime I want to thank you so much because I was going crazy and you solved everything!

Comment: You are welcome. My guess is that `{{x}, CHI[x]}` works because it has the same structure as multidimensional data (see 3rd syntax in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html)) and is therefore supported. Anyhow, I would always look at intermediate results to better understand what is going on. In this case, you can directly compare `Table[{CHI[x], {x}}, {x, 0, xMax, dx}]` and `Table[{CHI[x], x}, {x, 0, xMax, dx}]`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270962/how-can-i-find-the-inverse-of-an-interpolating-function